# NIFI JDBC Connection to MariaDB UTF8 support

Tags: mysql, mariadb, apache-nifi

when we run select convert(field using utf8) from the MySQL tool (which is on Windows using ODBC) my query works fine. When I run the same query from NIFI (which is on Linux using JDBC) my query does not work. What setting am I missing?

the JDBC connection string is

jdbc:mysql://10.10.x.x:y/warehouse

We are not getting an error. The one field that is being converted is empty.

Comment: please edit the question and specify connection parameters and the error that you have.

Comment: Perhaps you need `utf8mb4`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the full query you are running? When you use a function as a field to select from, the name returned is usually something funky, and due to the strict rules on field naming in Avro (which ExecuteSQL converts the data into), it often complains so you have to use an alias, something like `select convert(field using utf8) as field from myTable`.

But if you're not getting an error, I suspect maybe there's some session variable that is being set on your external MySQL tool and is not being set for NiFi's session. In the upcoming NiFi 1.9.0 release (via [NIFI-5780](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5780)) you'll be able to issue SET statements and such for the session, before executing your main query.

Otherwise, it's possible that the JDBC driver is returning a type to NiFi that it is not handling correctly (although for UTF8 I would expect it would report a String). I tried this with a `BINARY(10)` field and it works for me (using the latest master, not a released version), so I'm not sure what's going on there.